# How to create a new table from a dataset in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a logger which records a date/time and a value i.e.

```
05/06/21 11:29:43    0
05/06/21 11:29:48    0
05/06/21 11:29:53    0
05/06/21 11:29:58    1
05/06/21 11:30:03    1
05/06/21 11:30:08    1
05/06/21 11:30:13    0
```

The samples are recorded over a 30 day period.

I'd like to create a new dataset which filters this logging data to record the start and end time for each value within the current sequence i.e.

```
05/06/21 11:29:43    05/06/21 11:29:53    0
05/06/21 11:29:58    05/06/21 11:30:08    1
05/06/21 11:30:13    05/06/21 11:30:13    0
```

I would also (in addition) like a new dataset which is the COUNT of each value by date i.e.

```
05/06/21    0   4
05/06/21    1   3
```

How could either of these be best be achieved using Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1** - to go in cell `I3` of the sample sheet:

`=arrayformula({iferror(vlookup(query(if(if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,)=if(A2:A<>"",B1:B,),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),,row(A2:A)),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),row(A2:A),)),"where Col1 is not null",0),{row($A:$A),$A:$A},2,false),),iferror(vlookup(query(if(if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,)="",if(A2:A<>"",row(A2:A),),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),,row(A2:A))),"where Col1 is not null",0),{row($A:$A),$A:$B},{2,3},false),),query(if(if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,)="",if(A2:A<>"",row(A2:A),),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),,row(A2:A))),"where Col1 is not null",0)-query(if(if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,)=if(A2:A<>"",B1:B,),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),,row(A2:A)),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),row(A2:A),)),"where Col1 is not null",0)+1})`

[image]

**The working for part 1:**

Looking at **sequential** values of Amps in column B, we capture the **start** date/time from column A at the beginning of the sequence, then the **stop** date/time at the end of the sequence. Where there is only one value in a sequence (cell `B21`), the row is the **start** and **stop** value. The end value (cell `B119`) is also a **stop** value.

The following combines 3 formulas in and array `{1,2,3}`:

#1 - get start date/time (`vlookup` to get col A):

`=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(query(if(if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,)=if(A2:A<>"",B1:B,),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),,row(A2:A)),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),row(A2:A),)),"where Col1 is not null",0),{row($A:$A),$A:$A},2,false),))`

It looks at column B to see where the value above the current cell matches, but the one below is different. It also matches where the values above and below are different (single entry).

#2 - get stop date/time and Amps (`vlookup` to get col A and B):

`=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(query(if(if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,)="",if(A2:A<>"",row(A2:A),),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),,row(A2:A))),"where Col1 is not null",0),{row($A:$A),$A:$B},{2,3},false),))`

It looks at column B to see where the value below the current cell matches, but the one above is different. It also matches where the values above and below are different (single entry), and where the value below is blank (stop value).

#3 - get count (stop row# minus start row#, +1):

`=arrayformula(query(if(if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,)="",if(A2:A<>"",row(A2:A),),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),,row(A2:A))),"where Col1 is not null",0)-query(if(if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,)=if(A2:A<>"",B1:B,),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),,row(A2:A)),if(B2:B=if(A2:A<>"",B3:B,),row(A2:A),)),"where Col1 is not null",0)+1)`

**Part 2** - to go in cell `E2` of the sample sheet:

`=arrayformula(query({A:B,text(A:A,"dd/mm/yy")},"select Col3,Col2,count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col3,Col2 label Col2 'Value', Col3 'Day', count(Col2) 'Count' ",0))`

[image]

`QUERY` function used to select Amps, count their occurrence then group by day.

Comment: This works great for the second part of the question, but the min and max looks at the whole dataset, rather than just looking within the current sequence of 1's or 0's, if that makes sense

Comment: Are you able to share a sample sheet, read-only?

Comment: This sorts the second part `=arrayformula(query({A:B,text(A:A,"dd/mm/yy")},"select Col3,Col2,count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col3,Col2 label Col3 'Date',Col2 'Value'",0))`, but I can't understand why `0` is repeated in your initial new dataset (min 05/06/21 11:30:13 to max 05/06/21 11:30:13). If you don't want unique values in your column 2, are column 2 values based on a unique minute in col 1?

Comment: That's correct, there could be multiple changes from 0 to 1 each day, I need a summary of the timespan between each change. There could be up to 10 of each every 24 hours

Comment: No problem. Can you provide a sample dataset that better-represents what you have, and then how you want it to look? I can look at it later today.

Comment: Of course, here you go. I've added a Totals and Summary section. The Totals section works fine, it's the Summary section that we're now looking for

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1or0Aj7hsVqYVBizuBpa3MBqt6O6BR7WdwUlfh9bu25c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I was working on a simpler solution, so have just updated it as another answer below, to your first part.